# Calculate percentage of change between two CoNLL-X plain text files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, string-comparison

I've tried using sdiff but the results spew back 100%, which isn't accurate. I want to compare either string by string, or for any change to a tag or relation. Preferably command line.

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Removed Thanks and all